# Add iAd to Google Maps 1.7

Tags: ios7, iad, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to show a ad banner temporary on top of a google maps.

Therefore I have following code:

WPMapViewController.h:

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>
....
@interface WPMapViewController : UIViewController<ADBannerViewDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate>
```

WPMapViewController.m:

```
@implementation WPMapViewController {

    GMSMapView *mapView_;
    ADBannerView *_bannerView;
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        // On iOS 6 ADBannerView introduces a new initializer, use it when available.
        if ([ADBannerView instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(initWithAdType:)]) {
            _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithAdType:ADAdTypeBanner];
        } else {
            _bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
        }
        _bannerView.delegate = self;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:51.7
                                                        longitude:10.4
                                                             zoom:5.3];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    self.view = mapView_;

    mapView_.delegate = self;

    _bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, screenSize.height - 50, 320, 50);
    [self.view addSubview:_bannerView];
}
```

I guess because of `self.view = mapView_;` the _bannerView.delegate gets overwritten. When I run this code I can see the ad banner, but I cannot click it.
When I comment `self.view = mapView_;` out the banner works as expected but I cannot see a map.

`self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` is not a option for me because it shrinks the map.

What is the correct way to add a iAd banner to this UIViewController?

Comment: This could be due to the fact that subviews inherit the interaction property from the superview? Have you tried setting self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES; and see if that allows the banner view to get the touch?

Comment: Am I the first one who tries this? Or do you need more information?

Comment: I'm encountering similar issues regarding embedding a table view as well. The table view detects touch but does not scroll. This seems to have occurred after the 1.7 update.

Answer (score 1):

I modify your source by changing

`mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];`

to

`mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.view.frame camera:camera];`

then the map & iAd banner are shown, the banner is at the bottom of screen.

Comment: Thanks, but it is still not clickable

Comment: @AlexanderScholz , maybe you should try to add an App in DeveloperCenter/iTunesConnect, then link Xcode project to this App.